# My program doesnt run with computers without VS MSCR100D.dll is missing

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, compilation

I have been working very hard on a program for awhile.  I now need to send out my .exe to some friends so that they can test my collision code and intuitiveness of the simulation.

However when i give the .exe to friends it does this... I would post a picture but I don't have the credibility yet.  Here is the text

```
PlatformDemoA (1).exe- System Error

The program can't start because MSCR100D.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix the problem.
```

I'm going to assume this is because they don't have VS 2010 on their computers. **Is their any way to get this .exe to work on their computers without having Visual Studio?** Every place online says to install Visual Studio.

I am predicting that perhaps creating a "release" build instead of a debug might fix this up.  However when I try to build one... Suddenly errors show up relating to files I have included.  Apparently I am supposed to set the linker to include them in the release builds... I can't find that setting.  Here are the errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: PlatformDemoA, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  Triangle.cpp
1>Triangle.cpp(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GLTools.h': No such file or directory
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I went ahead and copied all of these things into the "release" folders.. That didn't fix things. I guess I really don't understand the linking of files.  If you would be willing to I could upload the project folder so you can tell me about how many time I have unnecessarily copied files.

My platform is Windows, and my target platform is also windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MSVCP100D.dll missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904213/msvcp100d-dll-missing)

Comment: You need to know that a release build uses a completely different set of project settings (import libraries, search paths, etc) from a debug build.  If you've been adjusting the configuration of the debug build during development, you'll now have to make all the same changes to the release build.

Comment: Where do i make the changes to the project settings for the release build?

Comment: @BenVoigt BTW I am in visual studio 2010

Comment: Just right-click your project and choose properties.  It's the same place you adjusted the debug configuration.  The dialog defaults to changing your active configuration, but there's a dropdown at the top you can use to go back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

The `MSCR100D.dll` is the debug runtime library and it's not recommended (actually **not even allowed** by Microsoft) to ship executables which link to it. Change it to "release" mode and either tell your customers to install the visual c++ runtime, or include the `MSVCR100.dll` into the folder, or, link the runtime statically. The release DLL should be already installed on most systems anyway.

You can set the link options in Visual Studio here:

> Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code
>   Generation -> Runtime Library

Comment: Also, you can't distribute the MS debug runtime anyway.  That would be in violation of the Microsoft's EULA.

Comment: What do i set it to iff I want it not to run with the MSCR100D.dll library?

Comment: @Andrew I told you. Set it to use the "relaese" runtime library. ( it's called `MSVCR100.dll` without `D` ) - see my answer above

Comment: My options are like this [link](http://i.imgur.com/gMJq3pY.png).  Do i choose one or type in the dll name?  I am very unfamiliar with this part of programming (linking files... dll's... runtimes... compile settings) so please bare with me.

Comment: Choose  one of the options not containing "Debug". The "Multi-Threaded" links the runtime statically, making you exe bigger. The "Multi-Threaded DLL" adds a dynamic link to the `MSVCR100.dll` that should be installed on most computers (if not, users have to install the Visual C++ Runtime Redistributable, or you can simply add the DLL to your  folder containing the exe)

Comment: Doing that causes a bunch of linker errors.  How do I resolve those.

Comment: If i build in debug it get [these](http://pastebin.com/92szj0Yh)  If I build in release i get [these](http://pastebin.com/ZQ1zZesE)  (these both have the hyperthread thing set)